# How to extract html input value by id with Selenium in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, web-scripting

How can I extract the value `4` using elementId `maxId` in Python.

```
<input type="hidden" id="maxId" value="4">
```

Python: 3.11.1, ChromeDriver: 109.0.5414.74

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably it would be enough to get the `value` attribute:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='path_to_your_driver')
driver.get("your site")
// Add wait here

driver.find_element(By.ID, "maxId").get_attribute("value")
```